# Entity Data Model Wizard (Crash) VS2019 Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am currently using VS2019 and yes i know other people asked this question but the crash other people are experiencing is not in the same window and didn't find any help.

So i am creating a new windows forms c# application and i am trying to add a new entity data model using the wizard.
Its all fine even when i click next after choosing the connection (which most people are experiencing the crash on)
Now i get to the next window:
[image: Wizard]

Now after i click next it silently crashes and does not create the model.

You might ask why you do not use EF6. i tried infact i have downloaded the MySql.Data.Entity with EF6 from nuget an now i get this:

[image]

What might be causing this problem?

Edit: The mysql connector that i am using is: Connector/NET 8.0.21

Comment: What driver is being used in the connection string?  The driver installed on machine for connection isn't compatible with the database.

Comment: i am using this Connector/NET 8.0.21 sorry didn't specify in the question i will edit it

Comment: What version of Entity Framework 5.0 are you using? https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0

Comment: I am not using EF5.0 any more.. i am trying with EF6. I have downloaded Mysql.EntityFrammework and installed connector.. both 8.0.21, now it is stopping upon going to choose EF6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so finally i solved it. I dont know if it was by luck, but i made a very extensive research to be able to do it.

Here are the steps:

MAKE THEM IN THIS ORDER so that app/web.config updates accordingly

1. Install latest .net Connector from mysql
2. Install latest mysql for visual studio plugin

Now in you solution

3. Install the latest EF6 from nuget.
4. Install the following 2 oracle packages from nuget
   [image: Oracle Packages]
5. Install mysql.data.entityframework
6. Rebuild the solution

Now create the Entity Data Model using wizard.

I tried on multiple solutions and it worked like a charm every time!